# "Element type is invalid: expected a string" in the definition of my main component: export const Autocomplete = (props) => {....}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react.

My main component is defined in the way:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
export const Autocomplete = (props) => {

return (
<div className="wrapper">
  hello
</div>
);
};
```

I am getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

this is my index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
 <StrictMode>
  <App />  <!--my main component-->
 </StrictMode>,
rootElement
);
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

You've made your main component a named export named `Autocomplete`, but you are importing a default component called `App`.

Try this:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Autocomplete } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
 <StrictMode>
  <Autocomplete />  <!--my main component-->
 </StrictMode>,
rootElement
);
```

## Explaining Named vs Default Exports

There are two ways of exporting and each way requires you to import the exported member differently.

### Named Export/Import

Named exports have to be imported using the same name as the exported member. The import will also have braces around the imported members. You can export multiple members from a single file.

`foobar.js`

```js
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = 'bar';
const baz = 'baz';

// or

const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
const baz = 'baz';
export {foo, bar};
```

`main.js`

```js
import { foo, bar } from './foobar'
```

### Default Export/Import

Default exports can be imported using any name you want. There will be no braces around the import. You can only default export a single member from a file.

`foobar.js`

```
export default {foo: '', bar: ''}; // directly exporting the value (an object), no variable declaration involved

// or

const foobar = {foo: '', bar: ''};
export default foobar;
```

`main.js`

```js
import foobar from './foobar';
const foo = foobar.foo;
const bar = foobar.bar;

// or

import whatever from './foobar';
const foo = whatever.foo;
const bar = whatever.bar;
```

### Named and Default Export/Import

You can also have both default and named exports from the same file. You may have seen this with React.

`foobar.js`

```js
export const foo = 'foo';
export const bar = 'bar';
export default foobar = 'foobar';
```

`main.js`

```js
import myFoobar, { foo, bar } from './foobar'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but I do `export default function Autocomplete(props)` it will work. Why?

Comment: @yavg I've updated my answer with an explanation of named vs. default exports.